# Displaying votes on public stream

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Am I allowed to display votes (self designed, not likes) of a photo competition app as stories on a public stream, e.g. "Becca has just voted for this picture?"?

If no, is there an alternative - for example using flowers as voting currency and displaying "Becca gave 6 flowers to pigglet's picture?

Thanks for all advice!

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, however you need publish_stream permissions in order to be able to post to user's wall. When you got that one, you can start posting on user's wall.

However, you didn't tell us which programming language you'll use, so I can't tell you any more advices